# Protobuf: How to fill one message with all fields from another message

Tags: protocol-buffers

I have two messages, one is empty and the other is full, I'd like to fill the empty one with all fields from the full one, just like `BeanUtils.copyProperties(dest, orig)` do. Seem there is no API that let me do something like this, any ideas?

Comment: What programming language?

Comment: There is a CopyFrom method as well in protobuf which seems to work in your case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a new `Builder` initialized from an existing `Message` using the `toBuilder()` method:

```
MyMessage.Builder builder = myMessage.toBuilder();
```

This is commonly used to change one field, like:

```
MyMessage newMessage = myMessage.toBuilder().setFoo(123).build();
```

If you already have a `Builder` and you want to copy fields from an existing mesasge into it, you can use `mergeFrom()`:

```
builder.mergeFrom(myMessage);
```

Note that fields that aren't set it `myMessage` will be left alone, hence the name "merge".

EDIT: If you're asking how to copy fields into an existing message object -- i.e. *not* a builder -- the answer is that you can't. Message objects are immutable, like Java's String type.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, however i think protobuf does not offer a way to fill one message from another, the method you mentioned, toBuilder, create a new message other than the original one, what I need is, fill one message from another message, not create a new one.

Comment: @July: As I said, if you already have a builder object that you want to modify you can use `mergeFrom()` to copy fields over. (Note that message objects (as opposed to builders) are immutable -- you cannot change a message object at all. So if you're asking how to copy into an existing message object, you can't.)